# Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?

Tags: python

In a similar way to using varargs in C or C++:

```
fn(a, b)
fn(a, b, c, d, ...)
```

Comment: I refer the honorable lottness to podcast 53: http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4111.html?loomia_si=t0:a16:g2:r2:c0.246273:b24677090

Comment: I gotta go with Mr Lott on this one. You can quickly get an authorative answer on this one in the Python docs, plus you'll get a feel for what else is there in the docs. It is to your benefit to get to know those docs if you plan on working in Python.

Comment: @DavidSykes Link is broken

Comment: The episode #53 "let's go Rio" cannot be the one mentioned by @DavidSykes in 2009, since it was recorded in 2013. Strangely, there was another #53 also recorded in 2011, also after David's comment: https://open.spotify.com/episode/3KVIJQoDDJWcAJzCjnKDio?si=4de4702aa3384761

Comment: @ouranos Could it be this #53? https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/page/46/

Answer (score 541, accepted):

Yes. You can use `*args` as a *non-keyword* argument. You will then be able to pass any number of arguments.

```
def manyArgs(*arg):
  print "I was called with", len(arg), "arguments:", arg

>>> manyArgs(1)
I was called with 1 arguments: (1,)
>>> manyArgs(1, 2, 3)
I was called with 3 arguments: (1, 2, 3)
```

As you can see, Python will *unpack* the arguments as a single tuple with all the arguments.

For keyword arguments you need to accept those as a separate actual argument, as shown in [Skurmedel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/919720/28169).

Comment: Also important...one may find a time when they have to pass an unknown number of arguments to a function.  In a case like this call your "manyArgs" by creating a list called "args" and passing that to manyArgs like this "manyArgs(*args)"

Comment: This is close, but this is unfortunately not general enough: `manyArgs(x = 3)` fails with `TypeError`. Skumedel's answer shows the solution to this. The key point is that the general signature of a function is `f(*list_args, **keyword_args)` (not `f(*list_args)`).

Comment: The type of `args` is `tuple`. `kwargs` means **keyword args**. The type of `kwargs` is `dictionary`.

Comment: Just `for arg in args:` for iterating through passed args

Comment: I have to pass variable number of integer parameters followed by optional string, can I call use xxx(*arg: int, log: str = "") ? The variety in the number of parameters is small 0, 1, 2 or 3, so I can use overloads but it seems like it is not not available in python.

Answer (score 260):

Adding to unwinds post:

You can send multiple key-value args too.

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    # kwargs is a dictionary.
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
         print "%s = %s" % (k, v)

myfunc(abc=123, efh=456)
# abc = 123
# efh = 456
```

And you can mix the two:

```
def myfunc2(*args, **kwargs):
   for a in args:
       print a
   for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
       print "%s = %s" % (k, v)

myfunc2(1, 2, 3, banan=123)
# 1
# 2
# 3
# banan = 123
```

They must be both declared and called in that order, that is the function signature needs to be *args, **kwargs, and called in that order.

Comment: Not sure how you got myfunc(abc=123, def=456) to work, but in mine (2.7), 'def' can't be passed in this function without getting a SyntaxError. I assume this is because def has meaning in python. Try myfunc(abc=123,fgh=567) instead. (Otherwise, great answer and thanks for it!)

Comment: @Dannid: No idea either haha... doesn't work on 2.6 or 3.2 either. I'll rename it.

Comment: When you say 'called in that order', do you mean passed in that order? Or something else?

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu: Yeah. Keyword arguments must come last when you call it. They always come last if you have non-keyword arguments in the call too.

Comment: For Python 3: Just exchange `print a` with `print(a)`, and `kwargs.iteritems():` with `kwargs.items()`.

Comment: What if you want to pass in arguments accepted by `logger.info()`? For example, `myLogger('Error: %s', err)`

Answer (score 28):

If I may, Skurmedel's code is for python 2; to adapt it to python 3, change `iteritems` to `items` and add parenthesis to `print`. That could prevent beginners like me to bump into:
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` and search elsewhere (e.g. [Error “ 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' ” when trying to use NetworkX's write_shp()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418498/6358973)) why this is happening.

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
for k,v in kwargs.items():
   print("%s = %s" % (k, v))

myfunc(abc=123, efh=456)
# abc = 123
# efh = 456
```

and:

```
def myfunc2(*args, **kwargs):
   for a in args:
       print(a)
   for k,v in kwargs.items():
       print("%s = %s" % (k, v))

myfunc2(1, 2, 3, banan=123)
# 1
# 2
# 3
# banan = 123
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding to the other excellent posts.

Sometimes you don't want to specify the number of arguments **and** want to use keys for them (the compiler will complain if one argument passed in a dictionary is not used in the method).

```
def manyArgs1(args):
  print args.a, args.b #note args.c is not used here

def manyArgs2(args):
  print args.c #note args.b and .c are not used here

class Args: pass

args = Args()
args.a = 1
args.b = 2
args.c = 3

manyArgs1(args) #outputs 1 2
manyArgs2(args) #outputs 3
```

Then you can do things like

```
myfuns = [manyArgs1, manyArgs2]
for fun in myfuns:
  fun(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(dic):
    if 'a' in dic:
        print dic['a'],
        pass
    else: print 'None',

    if 'b' in dic:
        print dic['b'],
        pass
    else: print 'None',

    if 'c' in dic:
        print dic['c'],
        pass
    else: print 'None',
    print
    pass
f({})
f({'a':20,
   'c':30})
f({'a':20,
   'c':30,
   'b':'red'})
____________
```

the above code will output

```
None None None
20 None 30
20 red 30
```

This is as good as passing variable arguments by means of a dictionary

Comment: This is terrible code. Far better would be: `f = lambda **dic: ' '.join(dic.get(key, 'None') for key in 'abc')`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it, besides the nice answers already mentioned, depends upon the fact that you can pass optional named arguments by position. For example,

```
def f(x,y=None):
    print(x)
    if y is not None:
        print(y)
```

Yields

```
In [11]: f(1,2)
1
2

In [12]: f(1)
1
```