# List of dictionaries: get() schould loop over list

Tags: python, dictionary

I know it is easy to implement.

I want a dictionary like class, which takes a list of dictionaries in the constructor.

If you read from this dict by key, the dict-class should check the list of dictionaries and return the first value. If none contains this key KeyError should be thrown like a normal dict.

This dictionary container should be read only for my usage.

Comment: What if this dictionary class internally combines this dictionary into 1 dictionary?

Comment: The new dictionary should contain only a list of dicts. No data should be copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be describing [`collections.ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), which will be in the next version of Python (3.3, expected to go final later this year). For current/earlier versions of Python, you can copy the implementation from the [`collections` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/collections/__init__.py).

Comment: Just some seconds after asking, I found a solution in django: MergeDict: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py  Nice to know, that ChainMap will be in Python in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answer to the question: what if you just define method that merge all dictionaries into one? Why make new class for it?
How to merge: [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression) 
Varargs: [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: If this is not really answer, then you should have put this in as a comment to the question, not as an answer!

Comment: Well, it is not straightforward answer, but it makes required task and, from my point of view, makes it better than additional class.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement this with this logic.

1. Iterate over all the dictionaries in the list.
2. For each dictionary, see if it has the required key by using  `key in value` statement.
3. If value is found, return the value from the function.
4. If you have iterated over all dictionaries, and value is not found, Raise KeyError exception.