# Polynomy function with changing number of parameters

Tags: python, function, dynamic, parameters

is it possible (in Python) to define a polynomial type of function that has changing amount of parameters? Number of parameters should change according to number of data series that I have in my input file.

Currently I have something like this:

```
def y(x, a0, x2, x3, x4):
    y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3
    return y
```

I could of course set parameters of higher order to zero by extra parameter but would there be some better way.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the arguments and evaluate the polynomial using [Horners method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), which is very efficient.

```
def y(x, *args):
  y = 0
  for a in reversed(args):
    y = y*x+a
  return y
```

You can find a heap more details about variable numbers of arguments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function).

Comment: see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) for an explanation for Horner's method

Comment: according to the signature in the question you have to revert args...your algorithm works if you loop from a_n to a_0

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke Correct. I've fixed that now by adding "reversed".

Answer (score 3):

an even simpler version using a generator expression

```
def y(x, *args):
  return sum(a * x ** i for i, a in enumerate(args))
```

and a Horner version using reduce

```
def horn(x, *args):
    return reduce(lambda y, a: y * x + a, reversed(args))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def y(x, *args):
  y = 0
  i = 0

  for a in args:
    y += a * x ** i
    i += 1

  return y

print y(2, 1, 2) # 2 * 2 ^ 0 + 2 * 2 ^ 1 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it would be much cleaner to provide polynomial as a single argument, namely a list of coefficients:

```
 def eval_poly(x, poly):
     ....

 eval_poly(10, [1, 2, 3]) # evaluate (1 + 2x + 3x^2)(10)
```

This way you can handle polynomials like ordinary values, for example:

```
 def add_poly(p1, p2):
     """Add two polynomials together"""
     ...

 p1 = [1,2,3]
 p2 = [4,5,6]

 print eval_poly(10, add_poly(p1, p2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with data files and evaluating polynomials, you could probably benefit from using `numpy`, which also includes [`numpy.polyval`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) for evaluating polynomials.