# Passing n arguments to a function in Python

Tags: python, arguments

I have a function that takes a variable amount of variables as arguments. How would I the contents of `some_list` in the example below to my `myfunc2()`

```
def myfunc1(*args):
    arguments = [i for i in args]
    #doing some processing with arguments...
    some_list = [1,2,3,4,5] # length of list depends on what was  passed as *args
    var = myfunc2(???)
```

The only way I can think of is to pass a list or tuple to `myfunc2()` as argument, but maybe there is a more elegant solution so I don't have to rewrite `myfunc2()` and several other functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: `arguments = [i for i in args]` this is not needed as args is this ... (you may need to make it a list instead of a tuple)

Comment: your edit really confuses what your question is? is it how to pass arguments to a function?

Comment: It sort of already is in the answers below, but you probably want `var = myfunc2(*some_list)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args` is a tuple. `*args` converts `arg` to a list of arguments. You define `myfunc2` the same way as `myfunc1`:

```
def myfunc2(*args):
    pass
```

To pass arguments, you can either pass then one by one:

```
myfunc2(a, b, c)
```

of grouper with `*` operator:

```
newargs = (a, b, c)
myfunc2(*newargs)
```

or using a combination of both techniques:

```
newargs = (b, c)
myfunc2(a, *newargs)
```

The same apply for `**` operator, which converts dict to list of named arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that helps to solve my problem. So, I basically just have to prepare a set of tuples and can also use something like `*args` for the second function call.

Answer (score 2):

this is pretty widely available and easily googleable ... Im curious what you searched for that you couldnt find a solution

```
def myfunc1(*args):
    arguments = args
    some_other_args = [1,2,3,4]
    my_var = myfunc2(*some_other_args) #var is not an awesome variablename at all even in examples
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that `*args` for myfunc1 and myfunc2 are supposed to be different. e.g. `myfunc1()` takes "a", "b", "c", and `myfunc2()` should take something like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I updated the initial question, I hope it makes sense now. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
myfunc(*arguments)
```

same goes with keyword arguments such as:

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    # pass them to another, e.g. super
    another_func(*args, **kwargs)
```