# List all function argument names (no docu)

Tags: python, introspection

I am a relative beginner in Python and I am trying to use it to run some not-well-documented code. My question is, how can I get a list of possible arguments of a function or a class constructor using interactive shell, for example. Ideally, I would like to have something like dir(), but it should list not class members, but possible argument's names of a function.

If it is not possible, is there any other way to infer function arguments without looking inside the code?

Comment: If you are in *nix environment, use bpython

Comment: Keep in mind - in Python, functions can take [variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function) so this may not be that useful.

Comment: @thefourtheye [IPython](http://www.Ipython.org) is probably better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I believe its just a matter of taste. I like bpython in my Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `inspect.getargspec`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(bar, baz):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['bar', 'baz'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was searching for

Answer (score 4):

Use `help(function_object)` to have python format everything it knows about a given function for you.

You can also use the [`inspect.getargspec()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to get a named tuple overview of the arguments accepted. You can pass the result of that function to [`inspect.formatargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.formatargspec) to format that as a python function as well:

```
>>> from inspect import getargspec, formatargspec
>>> def demo(foo, bar, eggs='ham'): pass
... 
>>> getargspec(demo)
ArgSpec(args=['foo', 'bar', 'eggs'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=('ham',))
>>> formatargspec(*getargspec(demo))
"(foo, bar, eggs='ham')"
```

For the above example function, `help(demo)` prints:

```
Help on function demo in module __main__:

demo(foo, bar, eggs='ham')
```