# converting an int to a list containing the int

Tags: python, list

How can i convert an int into a list containing that int.

I've code:

```
y=x
```

Here the odds of x being a int to a list is 95% to 5%.
if x is a int then fine. but if x is a list, i had to use:

```
y=list(x)
```

but in this case it'll create problem for int.

I can declare x as a list for all the cases. but for just 10% of chances using a list is quite unnecessary.

Is there any other way, if i can convert a int to list (not to string) so that i can use `y=list(x)` all the time?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this: if it's a list, don't convert, but if it's an int, convert to a list? In that case, what are you trying to achieve with this? Are you writing a function that aims to accept both lists and integers?

Comment: @wei2912 i'm using y as a backup variable which will update the x later again. and x may contain a list or an int depending on the input given.

Comment: In that case, would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function suit your needs more as compared to comparison?

Comment: @wei2912 if i'll use a function, i've to use x as a global or capture the returned variable in x. which will increase the coding lines of the program. which i dont want.

Comment: noted, was wondering if you were using a function. Haidro's answer should suit you fine.

Comment: @wei2912 yep. Haidro's working smoothly... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put square brackets around it:

```
y = [x]
```

If you want to check whether your input is an integer or not, you can use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(x, int):
    y = [x]
else:
    y = list(x)
```

Comment: thanks. learnt something new. :D is there any other way without the condition statements.

Comment: @RatDon Not that I can think of, sorry