# Python: calling a function with varying number of arguments

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I want to write a function witch converts a dictionary into a Gtk-ListStore, where the Gtklist-store should have n columns, the first to to be key and value of the dictionary and the rest to be empty strings. N should be given by the user.

The constructor of ListStore demands for the types of the columns. How to specify them in the right number?

Here is the function supporting only 2 or 3 columns to demonstrate the problem:

```
def dict2ListStore(dic, size=2):
  if size == 2:
    liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    for i in dic.items():
       liststore.append(i)
    return liststore
  elif size == 3:
    liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)
    for i in dic.items():
       l = list(i)
       l.append("")
       liststore.append(l)
    return liststore
  else:
    print("Error!")
    return
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
liststore = Gtk.ListStore(*([str] * size))
```

`[str] * size` is a list with `size` repetitions of `str`.

`func(*args)` is the way to pass the values contained in a sequence `args`, as multiple arguments.

Comment: @Nudin A quick look at the (2.7) **[docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)** might be worthwhile.