# Variable arguments in python -- Possible or not?

Tags: python

How do you write a function in Python with variable arguments into the function and return variable number of outputs?  Is this even possible with the constraints?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function

Comment: @BrenBarn I think you mean [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Yes, but the discussion of `**kwargs` is before that so I decided to link to the top of the section.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this. This is quite similar to ellipses in Java. When supplied with a variable amount of arguments, you can unpack these arguments as a list which you can manipulate as you deem necessary.

```
def func(*args):
    print len(args) # num of vars
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, take a look at splat operator

```
def my_function(*a): #here a will be list or tuple depend wt u passed
    # do your stuff with a
```

`**a` for dictionary

Comment: any reason for downvote???

Comment: I think your answer's fine, though it could use some more explanation. In all honesty, this is definitely a duplicate, so I'll upvote to restore justice.