# mapping functions with *args using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, mapping

Okay this one is confusing. My old piece of code has something like

```
map(lambda x:x.func1(arg1), other_args_to_be_mapped)
```

now I would like to make `arg1` -> `*args`

while `other_args_to_be_mapped` stays unchanged.

in `func1`, the length of arguments will be checked different operations. My questions are

1) which length will be checked? `arg1` or `other_args_to_be_mapped`

2) in `func1`, how should I set up the default? It was like

```
def func1(arg1=something)
```

but now with potential multiple arguments, I don't know what to do with the initialization. I want to be able to do something like

```
def func1(args*=something, something_else)
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. "arg1->*args" what does that mean? Could you provide a **concrete example** of what you have and what you want it to do?

Comment: It's simply changing `arg1` (which is a single arg) to `*args` (which can be one or multiple arguments based on inputs)

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do. Something I can plug into a script and run. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for [variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function). These can be mixed with fixed arguments, provided you obey a logical ordering (fixed arguments first, then keyword arguments or variable arguments).

For example, the following shows how map to a function that takes in one constant argument and one variable argument. If you would like different behaviour, please provide a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish

```
import random

class Foo:

    def get_variable_parameters(self):
        return [1] if random.random() > .5 else [1,2]

    def foo( self, arg, *args ):

        print("Doing stuff with constant arg", arg)

        if len(args) == 1:
            print("Good",args)
        else:
            print("Bad",args)

list(map( lambda x : x.foo( 'Static Argument', *x.get_variable_parameters()), [Foo(),Foo(),Foo()] ))
```

We don't know how many arguments are going to be passed to `foo` (in this trivial case, it's one or two), but the "*" notation accepts any number of objects to be passed

Note I've encapsulated `map` in `list` so that it gets evaluated, as in python3 it is a generator. [List comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) may be more idiomatic in python. Also don't forget you can always use a simple for loop - an obfuscated or complex `map` call is far less pythonic than a clear (but several line) for-loop, imo.

If, rather, you're trying to combine multiple arguments in a map call, I would recommend using the same variable argument strategy with the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function, e.g.,

```
def foo(a,*b): ...
map(lambda x : foo(x[0],*x[1]), zip(['a','b'],[ [1], [1,2] ]))
```

In this case, `foo` will get called first as `foo('a',1)`, and then as `foo('b',2,3)`

Comment: sorry but I can't provide the code as it's part of something else and I don't think I have permission to do it. I'll think about how I can make it more clear though. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You don't have to provide your production code, just create a minimal working example of what you're trying to accomplish