# If TypeError, return False

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I've created a python function:

```
def is_cayley_table(table):
    try:
        if type(table) is not list:
            return False
        else:
            n = len(table)
            poss_values = range(0,n)
            for i in range(0,n):
                if len(table[i]) != n:
                    return False
            for j in range(0,n):
                if type(table[i][j]) is int and table[i][j] in poss_values:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

I then call the function with an INVALID argument:

```
is_cayley_table([1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2])
```

I want the function to return "False", but at the moment I get this:

```
 File "C:/Users/Jack/OneDrive/Documents/comp_project.py", line 27, in <module>
    is_cayley_table([1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2])

TypeError: is_cayley_table() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

If anyone could help, I would be very appreciative.

Jack

Comment: I know. I'm trying to set up error handling so that if a user forgets the brackets, the function returns false, as opposed to a TypeError.

Comment: If you want your function to accept any number of arguments, you can define it using `def is_cayley_table(*args)`. See [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You're catching type errors within the function, but the problem is in *calling* the function; this cannot be caught within the function itself.

I'm not sure why you need to be able to call the function with invalid arguments, but one way to support this would be to accept any arguments with the `*args` syntax, then check what you have:

```
def is_cayley_table(*args):
    if len(args) != 1:
        return False
    table = args[0]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel - v helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't supply a function with more parameters than it has been declared to take. That is the biggest problem here.

So if you provide the function with 1 parameter and you put something like

```
is_cayley_table(([1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2]))
```

It will work as expected

Comment: I understand that. I was trying to do some error handling if the user (mistakenly) entered more than one argument.

Comment: If this function is the backend of some front end UI then you should handle user input before passing values to the function (in a `handleUserInput` type function). If you're developing an API or something else that a developer will be using, you should trust the developer not to make such a simple mistake.