# Storing a list of numpy arrays into local files?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am currently working on training a neural network and the preprocessing step takes a while to go through, especially when I want to tweak the parameter of my network structure. My input data consist of a list of numpy arrays, stored in 4 different variables. Is possible to store these list of numpys into local files, such that I just could load them and start the training rather than loading the raw files and begin preprocess that.

Comment: Read the docs of ```np.savez()```.

Comment: Yes. I just saw that.. can i give a list a input..?

Comment: Give it the output filename/path first, then each object individually.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis I am not sure I understand?

Comment: @user7654132 Check [this SO-question about variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function) and the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: @user7654132 see my edited answer for a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save numpy arrays using [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) (or [numpy.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) for multiple arrays at once) and load them again using [numpy.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load).

e.g. saving arrays:

```
import numpy
test_array_1 = numpy.ones([5, 6]) #creating a test array
test_array_2 = numpy.zeros([6, 7]) #creating a test array
numpy.savez("testfile.npz", test_array_1=test_array_1, test_array_2=test_array_2) #saving my two test arrays
```

e.g. loading arrays

```
import numpy
data = numpy.load("testfile.npz") #loading the two arrays into a variable called 'data'
print(data["test_array_1"]) #using one array directly
test_array_2 = data["test_array_2"] #assigning one to a varibale
```

Comment: I guess `np.savez()` might be better in my case?--

Comment: If you're always saving and loading those 4 together then yes, savez would be fine.