# Decorator approach to function polymorphism in Python 3

Tags: python, python-decorators, parametric-polymorphism

I have a function `f` that takes in the arguments `i`, `A` and `B`. `i` is a counter and `A` and `B` are lists or constants. The function just adds the i-th element of `A` and `B` if they are lists. Here's what I have written in Python 3.

```
def const_or_list(i, ls):
    if isinstance(ls, list):
        return ls[i]
    else:
        return ls

def f(i, A, B):
    _A = const_or_list(i, A)
    _B = const_or_list(i, B)
    return _A + _B

M = [1, 2, 3]
N = 11
P = [5, 6, 7]
print(f(1, M, N)) # gives 13
print(f(1, M, P)) # gives 8
```

You will notice that `const_or_list()` function is called on two (but not all) of the input arguments. Is there a decorator (presumably more Pythonic) approach to achieve what I am doing above?

Comment: This can help you [can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more pythonic in this case is not with a decorator.  I would get rid of the `isinstance`, use a try/except instead and get rid of the intermediate variables:

**Code:**

```
def const_or_list(i, ls):
    try:
        return ls[i]
    except TypeError:
        return ls

def f(i, a, b):
    return const_or_list(i, a) + const_or_list(i, b)
```

**Test Code:**

```
M = [1, 2, 3]
N = 11
P = [5, 6, 7]
Q = (5, 6, 7)
print(f(1, M, N))  # gives 13
print(f(1, M, P))  # gives 8
print(f(1, M, Q))  # gives 8
```

**Results:**

```
13
8
8
```

**But I really need a decorator:**

Fine, but it is a *lot* more code...

```
def make_const_or_list(param_num):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args = list(args)
            args[param_num] = const_or_list(args[0], args[param_num])
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@make_const_or_list(1)
@make_const_or_list(2)
def f(i, a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good point about the try and catch exception approach. Indeed the decorator approach seems lengthier code-wise. But it simplifies the final function to a simple one-liner. In my actual use case where formulas are far more complicated and constantly changed, clarity is paramount.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def const_or_list(i, ls):
    if isinstance(ls, list):
        return ls[i]
    else:
        return ls

def f(*args):
    i_ip = args[0]
    result_list = []
    for i in range(1, len(args)):
        result_list.append(const_or_list(i_ip, args[i]))
    return sum(result_list)

M = [1, 2, 3]
N = 11
P = [5, 6, 7]
print(f(1, M, N)) # gives 13
print(f(1, M, P)) # gives 8
```