# call subprocess with various optional parameters

Tags: python-3.x

How can I call a subproccess with a lot of optional parameters?

```
def subproccess_call(process_name, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
  cmd = ['sudo', '%s', '%s', '%s'] % (process_name, arg1, arg2)
  subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout= subprocess.PIPE,                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The subproccess method can bei called with zero, one or two additional arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: defining a function with variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192234/python-defining-a-function-with-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Is there any reason why the arguments aren't passed in directly as a list?

Comment: trying to write clean code - its not desirable to use *kwargs. On the other hand a list will support the open close principle. I'll think about it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking variadic arguments if they are just that. Many python functions do, and the feature exists for a reason. What makes you think variadic arguments are inappropriate here?

Comment: Here is it mentioned as alternative way but not the best way https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/  with an example: send('Hello', ['God', 'Mom', 'Cthulhu']). The problem is that you can specify any argument you like so its not clear for the caller of the method