# Write a function that adds lists elements using *args

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sum

I would like to write a function that calculates scalar sum of several vectors. It should take several lists as arguments eg.

```
def add_lists(x, y, z):
   # return sum of x, y, z

x = add_lists([1, 2],[2, 1],[3, 1])
# x returns [6, 4]
```

It is easy to do it for only two arguments, but how can I do it using *args if they are more than two, so that my `add_lists` will return [6, 4]?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function

Comment: How would you sum it if passed a `list` of two-`tuple`s? The answer is the same.

Comment: @NishanthShetty: That other question asks is varargs is possible, but the OP clearly knows about `*args`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you wish to write a function that can take any amount of vectors and return the sum? Then yes, you would need to use `*args` like so:

```
def add_lists(*args):
    final_vector = [0, 0]
    for vector in args:
        final_vector[0] += vector[0]
        final_vector[1] += vector[1]
    return final_vector
```

Basically, treat `args` as a list - containing all the arguments passed through when you call the function.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` and `*args`:

```
def add_lists(*args):
    return [sum(x) for x in zip(*args)]

x = add_lists([1, 2],[2, 1],[3, 1])
# x is [6, 4]
```

Comment: This is the best and most general solution, and unlike other solutions here will automatically scale up if the length of all "vectors" changes.

Comment: What I like here is that `zip(*args)` and `def add_lists(*args)` is using the `*` operator in two different ways: The first way is to demonstrate that multiple arguments can be passed through, whereas the second way is actually unpacking `args` into the `zip` function

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
def add_lists(*args):
    s1 = sum(i[0] for i in args)
    s2 = sum(i[1] for i in args)
    return [s1,s2]

res = add_lists([1, 2],[2, 1],[3, 1])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[6, 4]
```