# How to define a function that takes any number of arguments?

Tags: python

I want to make a function that can for example sum up all arguments:

```
def sum(#elements):
    return(a+...#all elements)

print(sum(1,3,4))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variable-length arguments**

You may need to process a function for more arguments than you specified while defining the function. These arguments are called variable-length arguments and are not named in the function definition, unlike required and default arguments.

```
def sum( *vartuple ):
   total = 0
   for var in vartuple:
      total += var
   return total
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a `*` before the argument.

```
def my_sum(*args):
    total = 0
    for arg in args:
        total += arg
    return total
```

Now you can call it like `my_sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: Might as well use `sum(args)`