# Python function with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord bot using python.

I have a function

```
def search(userName):
    # ...
```

but the userName MAY contain spaces

Eg.

```
Enter userName: Me Head
```

and I want the function to read bot arguments given and join them together so it forms "MeHead"

Currently if I try to run my `search(userName)` function with two inputs it will just take the first input so

```
Enter userName: Me Head
```

will just run `search("Me")` and ignore anything after that first input

Comment: Shouldn't there still only be a single argument, even if the username contains spaces? Either it's a single string (without spaces) `'John'`, or it's a single string (with spaces) `'Me Head'`.

Comment: Anyway, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function

Comment: Looks like it should be responsability of the caller function (the one calling your `search()` function) to make sure it passes the user input as a single string...

Comment: The input is kinda different because it's given from a discord server so the string will end when the user types a space

Comment: Could you include the entirety of at least the first few lines of the function, including any decorators that you've applied to it?  `discord.py` does a lot of parsing behind the scenes with certain decorators, especially the `Bot.command` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The input is received is a string, so it does not matter if there are or no spaces. To remove spaces, you must use the function:

```
str.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: This works if I do it on python IDLE but when I try to replicate it on discord it won't work. The string ends after the first space