# Generalizing my python function

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make my function be able to accept as many inputs or as little inputs as needed.

Currently I have 3 inputs that are hard coded (`loc1`, `loc2`, `loc3`). Is there a way to keep the inputs variable so if I just had 1 input, or if I have 5 inputs, my function can be flexible?

```
def np_array(loc1, loc2, loc3):
    loc_a = np.array(loc1)
    loc_b = np.array(loc2)
    loc_c = np.array(loc3)

    pressure_vector1 = np.subtract(loc_a, loc_c)
    pressure_vector2 = np.subtract(loc_a, loc_b)

    movement_vector = np.add(pressure_vector1, pressure_vector2)

    return movement_vector
```

Comment: see `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Comment: you could also simply pass a list as the argument, which you fill with your args.

Comment: you need variable arguments. ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*args` or `**kwargs` for this.

In Python, the single-asterisk form of `*args` can be used as a parameter to send a non-keyworded variable-length argument list to functions. It is worth noting that the asterisk (`*`) is the important element here, as the word args is the established conventional idiom, though it is not enforced by the language.

The double asterisk form of `**kwargs` is used to pass a keyworded, variable-length argument dictionary to a function. Again, the two asterisks `(**)` are the important element here, as the word `kwargs` is conventionally used, though not enforced by the language.

Like `*args`, `**kwargs` can take however many arguments you would like to supply to it. However, `**kwargs` differs from `*args` in that you will need to assign keywords.

To learn more about this I recommend [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3) awesome post

Answer (score 0):

You could use default arguments to make the function more flexible like:

```
def np_array(loc1=None, loc2=None, loc3=None):
    # ensure you don't use None type variables
    if loc1 is None:
        loc1 = 'sensibleDefaultValueGoesHere'
    # repeat as often as needed before you proceed with the

    # actual calculation ...
```