# How do I add indefinite number of list together and output a single list?

Tags: python

The inputs will be lists (which is the number of list is indefinite), the function is supposed to iterate through all the index and add each value of the list for same index for all the inputted list mathematically together. The output will be the a list which consist of all the added values

For example:
lista = [1,2,3] listb = [2,3,5] listc = [-3,2,1]
outputlist = [0,7,9]
My function below is only able to add 2 list together, I want no restrictions as to how many list. How do I do that?
Thank you very much in advance

```
def listadd(a,b):
    counter = 0
    list = []
    while counter < len(a):
        list.append(a[counter]+b[counter])
        counter += 1
    return list
```

Comment: You know the python zip function?

Comment: Please include more information about expected inputs/outputs.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/919680/3001761

Comment: Side note: **never** (even as an example) shadow built-ins, e.g. use `lst`, `L` or `list_` instead of `list` as your argument name.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific in the question, I meant to add each values of the same list index mathematically, not combining the list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have seen that example, however I do not know how to add the values of same index mathematically together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def listadd_new(*lsts):
    return list(map(sum, zip(*lsts)))

assert listadd([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) == listadd_new([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Or with a list comprehension for increased readability: `return [sum(values) for values in zip(*lsts)]`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip