# Define a function in python to make the NaN values zero with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function which can fill zero in all the `Nan` values for all the columns of the input dataframe.

The function takes 1 fixed argument (dataframe name) and variable number of arguments for column names in the dataframe.

I am using below code -

```
def makeNa(df,*colnames):
    for col in colnames:
        return df.fillna({col:0},inplace=True)
```

The function works when I pass only one column name e.g. `makeNa(df_test,'USA')` -it makes all the Nan values as zero for column 'USA' 
but the function doesn't work while inputting more than one column names e.g. `makeNa(df_test,'USA','Japan')` --> it doesnt zero the Nan values in column 'Japan'

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with Japan, given that you return for USA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: You should write your question more carefully. 
No indentation in a python code - especially when defining a function - is usually a bad sign.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What specifically happens?

Comment: You have an unconditional `return` statement in a `for` loop; the loop will only iterate once.

Comment: @MagnusReftel - No, it is not entirely the  duplication. My query is variable argument function to make the Nan value zero.I corrected the title to avoid confusion

Comment: @JammyDodger thanks for point it out. I have corrected it

Answer (score 2):

You don't let the loop end, you return at the first iteration. You could do something like:

```py
def makeNa(df, *colnames):
    df[colnames] = df[colnames].filna(0)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def makeNa(df,*colnames):
    for col in colnames:
        df.fillna({col:0},inplace=True)
    return df
```

you are returning in for loop , instead try to return outside.