# Is there a way to use *args, to dynamically take as many as inputs I want in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

```html
def f(a, b,c,d):
    x = open('data.txt', 'r')
    for line in x:
        line = line[a:b] + ':' + line[c:d] + ':'
        x2 = open('data2.txt', 'a+')
        x2.writelines(line)
f(0,2,2,6)
```

I have raw data which is something like

```
1231231231231233453453223768729318974389124387\n
1234534534534543242145791208937867328918373892\n
8765432456765434568987692839471281027128012398\n
5787624567456787432343512487320190928390129383\n
```

I want to divide data based on their location
for example: `[0:2]` could be column 1 and `[2:6]` is column 2 and so on.
when I'm calling the function `f()`, Is there any way in python where we can overload or dynamically enter parameters like 
`f(0,2,2,6,6,10,10,14.......)`

**output:**

```
57:8762:4567:8743.....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Python supports special input argument modifiers. The `*` says treat the argument as a list and assign any remaining input arguments to that list. (The `**` says treat the arg as a dict and assign all keyword pairs to it.)  So, you can have a func like:

```
def (a, b, *cd):
    "do something for 'a' and 'b'"
    for e in cd:
        "do something for each arg 'e' in 'cd'"
```

The arg 'cd' can be empty or it can be long, depending on what params you use to call the func.
If you expect `cd` will always come in pairs, you can change the `for` loop to:

```
    for c, d in zip(cd[::2], cd[1::2]):
        "do something for 'c' and 'd'"
```

The `zip` function takes two lists and makes a list of tuples. So, the above `for` loop takes a single list and breaks it into pairs, an even and an odd. So, if 'cd' is (x0, y0, x1, y1), the `zip` call would yield ((x0, y0), (x1, y1)).