# Optimizing multiple function input in Python

Tags: python, function

```
final=list(product(char1,char1,char1,char1,char1,char1,char1,char1,char1,char1))
```

Let’s say the number of `char1` in the `product` function depends on an input. For example, there will be 5 `char1` in the `product` function if the input is 5.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Just use parameter destructuring:

```py
count = int(input())
chars = [char1] * count
final = list(product(*chars))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just multiply it:

```
c = [char1]*5
f = list(product(*c))
```

Replace `5` with the count

Answer (score 0):

```
word=input()
n=int(input())
your_list=[word for i in range(n)]
print(*your_list)
```

[image]