# Is it possible to add multiple inputs for one parameter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where it takes in a list of numbers and then it will only take the **even** numbers and print it.

My problem is that I am trying to understand how to give it the list of numbers for it to take in to the parameter.

Here is my code:

```
def getEvens(NumList):
    NumList = []
    for num in NumList:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num, end = ",")
getEvens(39,94,3,4,5,67) # <--- How can I make this all go to one parameter?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: The above dupe explains how to do what you want. The simpler, more usable way would just be to pass a list though: `getEvens([39,94,3,4,5,67])`. Also, get rid of `NumList = []`. That will break things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def getEvens(NumList):
    for num in NumList:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num, end = ",")

getEvens([39,94,3,4,5,67])
```

Remove `NumList = []` because this just overwrites the parameter with an empty list

wrap the number params in `[]` to make them into a list when calling the function

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-keyword argument called ***args** which lets you pass several values at a time. [More details on args here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/#:%7E:text=The%20special%20syntax%20*args%20in,used%20with%20the%20word%20args.)

```
def getEvens(*nums):
    for num in nums:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num, end = ",")

getEvens(39,94,3,4,5,67)
```

You can makes this more simple using **filter** function

```
nums = (39,94,3,4,5,67)

getEvens = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, nums))

print(','.join(getEvens))
```