# Learn Python the Hard way ex40 : TypeError :object () takes no parameter

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Song(object):
    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
    def sing_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line
happy_bday = Song("Happy Birthday to you",
            "I might get sued for this",
            "So I'll stop right here")
            
print happy_bday

happy_bday.sing_song()
```

***This gives me error ***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex36.py", line 9, in <module>
    "So I'll stop right here")
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is python 2? If not that should be `print(line)` and `print(happy_bday)`

Comment: Also the function is `__init__` there are _2_ underscores... Also to take variable number of arguments you'll need to use `*` -> `def __init__(self, *lyrics)`

Comment: `__init__` is a special python method, you need two underscores on either side

Comment: Applicable -> [What __init__ and self do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625083/15497888) and [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919680/15497888)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```py
def __init__(self, lyrics):
```

instead of

```py
def _init_(self, lyrics):
```

Inside your class. Also, your `__init__` function takes only 1 argument, while you're passing in 3. If you want it to take all your arguments as a list, you could use

```py
def __init__(self, *lyrics):
```

And `lyrics` will be a list of all your arguments you passed in.

Comment: This is only part of the solution.

Comment: Yep, I've updated it