# How to have function with multiple parameters without having to type every single parameter?

Tags: python

so I was coding a library (again) for fun:

```
import random
def pickRandom(value):
    return random.random(value)
print(pickRandom(10, 2, 40))
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
TypeError: pickRandom() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

What I'm trying to do here is I want to have multiple parameters in one function with typing just one parameter name. example: value. I want to have multiple values in that one parameter. instead of typing them all like parmeter1 parameter2. I'm pretty sure this is possible because of the "random" module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: @emptyhua python. not c++

Comment: @Rydex No problem. Happy coding :)