# How do I use python to display multiple answers for n amount of input sets of 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv

I want do take my function

```
def function_name(inputa, inputb)
    #long formula which uses 2 inputs
    return answer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_name(float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]))
```

input to bash

```
 python3 function_name.py 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.5
```

would like to take
inputa, inputb = 0.3, 0.2
and run formula for answer 1
then rerun formula with
inputa, inputb = 0.1, 0.5
and give the output for answer 2

this should work with n amount of inputs such as
python3 function_name.py 0.3 0.2
or  python3 function_name.py 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.6 0.7
and so on

expected output

```
answer 1 
answer 2
```

```
def function_name(inputa, inputb)
    #long formula which uses 2 inputs
    return answer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_name(float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]))
```

input:

```
python3 function_name.py 0.3 0.2
```

output:

```
answer
```

input:

```
python3 function_name.py 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.5
```

output:

```
answer1
answer2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

This does what you asked, but I'm pretty sure what you asked is not really what you wanted.  I've supplied a fake function just to show it working:

```
import sys
def function_name(inputa, inputb):
    #long formula which uses 2 inputs
    return inputa+inputb
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    while len(args) >= 2:
        a = args.pop(0)
        b = args.pop(0)
        print("Answer:", function_name(float(a), float(b)))
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py 0.5 0.7 1.2 1.5 2.5 2.9
Answer: 1.2
Answer: 2.7
Answer: 5.4
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

Comment: yea I believe I explained it wrong, I am using this equation for another program. this gives me 1 answer but I am looking for an answer for each inputa, inputb that is inputted n amount of times. sorry if this isn't making sense, It is part of a larger program. I had the formula working with just the 2 inputs but need to be able to run it with n amount of 2 inputs with n amount of answers per each 2 inputs

Comment: So, I'm guessing you didn't even try this code before responding.  This does not give you one answer.  If you supply 6 arguments, it prints out 3 answers, just as you asked.

Comment: I tried it but when I unit test it is shows 1 answer as well as running it in python I must be doing something wrong it shows me only the answer to the first two items

Comment: What do you mean by "unit test"?  Your function accepts two inputs and returns one output.  It's always going to do that.  It's the main program that handles the multiple arguments.

Comment: This solution with pop(0) is unnecessarily slow (O(n**2)) for long argv arrays. You may want to do `for i in range(1, len(sys.argv), 2):` instead (which is O(n)).

Comment: Now if you want to only call the function once, and it's the function that returns as many answers as there are pairs of arguments, that's possible too but that's another code.

Comment: That's not what you asked for.  You gave a specific example of the output you wanted.

Comment: yea you are right I think I ran the other way and get a list with the wrong answers will stick with the way you showed @Tim new to this

Comment: I guess I explained it wrong there will be other python scripts that calling this function and it needs to be able to input any number of sets of 2 for an answer with each set of 2

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation where the function works with several (pairs of) arguments; the function actually returns a generator for the answers:

```
import sys

def function_name(*args):
    for i in range(0, len(args)//2):
        inputa, inputb = args[2*i], args[2*i+1]
        #long formula which uses 2 inputs
        yield inputa + inputb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(list(function_name(*map(float, args))))
```

Example:

```
C:\Users\Swifty\.spyder-py3>python tmp.py 1 2 3 4 1.2 4.7
[3.0, 7.0, 5.9]
```

Note: I coded a protection against an odd number of arguments: the last one is ignored.

Example:

```
C:\Users\Swifty\.spyder-py3>python tmp.py 1 2 3 4 1.2
[3.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: how would I modify if I wanted to keep the input names for the formula ex: inputa inputb

Comment: You should have been able to figure this out.  `inputa = args[2*i]` / `inputb = args[2*i+1]`.

Comment: thanks yea just started with python apologies, I do appreciate the help